# Does the term $d ( \omega_{ab} \wedge \theta^a \wedge \theta^b )$ have any significance?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, geometry, boundary-terms

If $\omega_{ab}$ is the spin connection 1-form, and $\theta^a$ are the tetrad 1-forms, then one has the equality

\begin{equation}
\int \, d ( \epsilon_{abcd} \omega^{ab} \wedge \theta^c \wedge \theta^d ) = \int d^3 x \sqrt{h} K
\end{equation}

where $K$ is the extrinsic curvature scalar, and the second term is the GHY boundary term.

Is there a similar geometrical interpretation for the term

\begin{equation}
\int d ( \omega_{ab} \wedge \theta^a \wedge \theta^b)?
\end{equation}

Does this term have a name, or appear in any known theories? Is it zero?

One might also see similarities with these equations involving the Riemann curvature 2-form $R_{ab}$
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{abcd} R^{ab} \wedge \theta^c \wedge \theta^d = R
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
R_{ab} \wedge \theta^a \wedge \theta^b = R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} = 0.
\end{equation}

The first term is the usual Einstein-Hilbert lagrangian whereas the second is the Holst term. Therefore, the term I am asking about is the analog of the Holst term for the GHY boundary term.

**Edit:** @Adversing has claimed in the comments that the term is zero in Einstein gravity. Does anyone have a proof of this fact?

Comment: I think that it depends on the specific theory under consideration. In General Relativity, where torsion is assumed to be zero by construction, this term you mentioned vanishes, even though in more general theories of gravity (such as Einstein-Cartan theory or teleparallel gravity, where torsion is non-zero) this term does not necessarily vanish and contributes to the dynamics of the theory

Comment: @Adversing I would be unbelievably grateful if you would type a response providing the proof of why that term is zero in Einstein Gravity! It has been bedeviling me for a while!

Comment: The Holst term is NOT identical to zero. The variation of Holst term is only zero on shell, meaning it's zero once the Einstein field equation is satisfied.

Comment: @MadMax I think the terms "on shell" and "off shell" are somewhat formalism dependent, right? The Holst term is certain zero when the Bianchi identity is satisfied, which is true for an "off shell" metric w.r.t. the usual metric metric formulation of gravity, although it may not be zero "off shell" with respect to other formulations involving torsion. In any case, my question only really pertains to situations that are "on shell" in all senses of the word.

Comment: Are these of any help https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0669 , https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1298v4 ?